# How to prove $f:Z \to E$, given by $f(x) = 2x$ is bijective?

Tags: proof-verification

I know I must prove that $f$ is both injective and surjective. I've got the injective proof down. But I'm stuck on the surjective proof.

So far I have, for some $x,y ∈ Z$, $y = 2x \Rightarrow x = y/2$. Now does this prove that $f$ is surjective as well since $y$ would also $\in E$ (even numbers)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're essentially  correct. Be sure for the second part that you _start_ from the assumption that $y$ is even. What does that tell you about $y/2$?

Comment: Okay so just make sure to start with something like: for some x,y ∈ Z and y ∈ E?

Comment: You need to write clearer sentences. Start with $y\in E$. What precisely does this mean?

Comment: No. You start *only* with $y\in E$.

Comment: Okay gotcha. Thanks.

Umm  y∈E means that y is Even. I tried to keep the question short. But it describes the set E in our book, E being even integers.

Comment: What is your definition of an even number? Start there.